# JPQL joining two tables and adding parameter generates eclipseLink error

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipselink, jpql

So .. I have two tables Utilisateur and ReponsesTickets ( there's no trouble inserting selecting updating deleting from each table by itself) to make a join between these two tables i had to create a new Entity here's its code.

```
package projet.helpdesk.beans;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
//TEXTE - DATE_POST - NOM  - PRENOM - AGENCE - POSTE - DEPARTEMENT - ID_EMPLOYE
public class Jointure1 {
private String texte;
private String nom;
private String prenom;
private String Agence;
private String poste;
private String departement;
private int id_employe;
private Timestamp date_post;

public String getTexte() {
    return texte;
}
public void setTexte(String texte) {
    this.texte = texte;
}
public String getNom() {
    return nom;
}
public void setNom(String nom) {
    this.nom = nom;
}
public String getPrenom() {
    return prenom;
}
public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
    this.prenom = prenom;
}
public String getAgence() {
    return Agence;
}
public void setAgence(String agence) {
    Agence = agence;
}
public String getPoste() {
    return poste;
}
public void setPoste(String poste) {
    this.poste = poste;
}
public String getDepartement() {
    return departement;
}
public void setDepartement(String departement) {
    this.departement = departement;
}
public int getId_employe() {
    return id_employe;
}
public void setId_employe(int id_employe) {
    this.id_employe = id_employe;
}
public Timestamp getDate_post() {
    return date_post;
}
public void setDate_post(Timestamp date_post) {
    this.date_post = date_post;
}

}
```

That's the SQL instruction i'm trying to translate into JPQL.

```
SELECT u.nom, u.prenom, r.texte, r.date_post
FROM Utilisateur u, ReponseTicket r
WHERE u.id_emp = r.id_employe
AND r.id_ticket = ? ( parameter here )
```

This is the method in the DAO pattern.

```
    private static final String PARAM_TICKET           = "id_ticket";
    private static final String JPQL_SELECT ="SELECT u.nom, u.prenom, r.texte, r.date_post FROM Utilisateur u JOIN ReponseTicket r ON u.id_emp = r.id_employe AND r.id_ticket=:id_ticket";
    //^ Above is the JPQL instruction, not sure if it's correct.

    @PersistenceContext( unitName = "bdd_helpdesk_PU" )
    private EntityManager       em;

public List<Jointure1> trouverJointure( int id_ticket ) throws DAOException {
        List<Jointure1> liste;
        TypedQuery<Jointure1> query = em.createQuery(JPQL_SELECT, Jointure1.class);
        query.setParameter(PARAM_TICKET, id_ticket);
        try {
            liste = (List<Jointure1>) query.getResultList();
        } catch ( NoResultException e ) {
            return null;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new DAOException(e);
        }
        return liste;
    }
```

Then goes the ResponseForm that communicates with the DAO method.
this method collects the ticket id from the request and passes it to the DAOmethod to insert it into the JPQL instruction.

```
public List<Jointure1> recupererJointure(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    List<Jointure1> ljointure;
    int id = getId_ticket(request);
    if(id!=0){
        ljointure = reponseDao.trouverJointure(id);
    }else ljointure=null;
    return ljointure;
}
```

**Stacktrace**:

```
 Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-6168] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: Query failed to prepare, unexpected error occurred: [java.lang.NullPointerException].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=Utilisateur jpql="SELECT u.nom, u.prenom, r.texte, r.date_post FROM Utilisateur u JOIN ReponseTicket r ON u.id_emp = r.id_employe AND r.id_ticket=:id_ticket")
```

I don't know about the null pointer exception, the parameter id_ticket is visible in the URL.
However i didn't add the new Entity in the persistence.xml

```
http://localhost:4040/monprojet2/reponsesticket?id_ticket=62
```

This is the servlet.

```
   package projet.helpdesk.servlets;


@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/reponsesticket"})
public class Reponsestickets extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    private TicketDao ticketDao;

    @EJB
    private ReponseTicketDao reponseDao;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        CreationTicketForm ticketform = new CreationTicketForm(ticketDao);
        Ticket ticket = ticketform.recupererTicket(request);

        CreationReponseForm reponse = new CreationReponseForm(reponseDao);
        List<Jointure1> listereponse = reponse.recupererJointure(request);

        if(ticket==null)
        {
        response.sendRedirect("/connexion");
        } else {
            request.setAttribute("lreponse", listereponse);
            request.setAttribute("ticket", ticket);
            this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/ReponsesTickets.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Réponses ticket</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="inc/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<p>Test---> <br>votre id:${masession.idemp}<br>
Type:${masession.type}<br>
</p>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Réponses pour ticket id: ${ticket.id_ticket}</legend><br>
    <p>Sujet:</p> ${ticket.sujet} <br>
    <p>Description:</p> ${ticket.description}<br>
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    <c:forEach items="${lreponse}" var="reponse">
        <p>Nom: ${reponse.nom}</p>
        <p>Prenom: ${reponse.prenom }</p>
        <p>Réponse: ${reponse.texte }</p>
        <p>Date: ${reponse.date_post }</p>
        <br><br>
    </c:forEach>

    <br><br><br>


    <fieldset>
    <legend>Répondre:</legend>
    <form method="post" action="creerreponse" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
        <textarea rows="5" cols="36" name="texte"></textarea>${erreurs['texte']}<br/>
        <input type="hidden" name="id_employe" value="${masession.idemp}">
        <input type="hidden" name="id_ticket" value="${ticket.id_ticket}">
        <input type="hidden" name="type" value="${masession.type}">
        <input type="submit" value="Valider"><br/>
    </form>
    <p></p>
    </fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
  [2017-05-03T16:47:49.790+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=30 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1493826469790] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[projet.helpdesk.servlets.Reponsestickets]: Servlet.service() for servlet projet.helpdesk.servlets.Reponsestickets threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "nom"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.toInteger(ArrayELResolver.java:378)
    at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:198)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:188)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.evaluateExpression(PageContextImpl.java:1016)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.ReponsesTickets_jsp._jspx_meth_c_forEach_0(ReponsesTickets_jsp.java:143)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.ReponsesTickets_jsp._jspService(ReponsesTickets_jsp.java:85)
```

Comment: Since there is no RELATION between Utilisateur and ReponseTicket then you cannot "join" them in JPQL! Maybe if you just put a comma in there rather than "JOIN " ... like in the JPA spec

Comment: @NeilStockton Hello again .. can you please be more specific? like rewriting the JPQL instruction, there is naturally no relation between them but i'm going to join them through the common attribute "id_emp" and "id_employe" 
And i don't need to place the new Bean in the persistence.xml file?

Comment: Read a JPQL reference document. So there is no relation, hence you cannot use "JOIN". You can however do "FROM Class1 c1, Class2 c2" , which again you would find in any decent JPQL reference

Comment: In JPA 2.1 and higher you can do JOIN `ON CLAUSE` for entities with no relations.

Comment: `[2017-05-03T16:35:16.943+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [FINE] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.session./file:/C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/monprojet2/WEB-INF/classes/_bdd_helpdesk_PU.sql] [tid: _ThreadID=29 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1493825716943] [levelValue: 500] [[
  SELECT t0.nom, t0.prenom, t1.TEXTE, t1.DATE_POST FROM Utilisateur t0, ReponsesTickets t1 WHERE ((t0.id_emp = t1.ID_EMPLOYE) AND (t1.ID_TICKET = ?))
 bind => [62]]]`

I got it, now the SQL is invoked and working, ERROR is in the JSP now, i update the question.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi Ermm, no you cannot join unrelated entities in JPA 2.1. You can use "ON" yes, but not for unrelated entities. Some JPA providers may offer the ability to join unrelated entities but that is NOT in the JPA spec

Comment: @BuhakeSindi Yes thank you, i did read the reference, the SQL is invoked and the parameter was collected, now when passing the result list to JSP page, ( in the bottom of my question ) an error occurs 
    `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "nom"`

Comment: I tried this `System.out.println("CECI EST UN NOM:"+listereponse.get(0).getNom());` and it generated this error `java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to projet.helpdesk.beans.Jointure1
 at projet.helpdesk.servlets.Reponsestickets.doPost(Reponsestickets.java:46)`

Comment: Your are selecting data from JPA (u.nom, u.prenom, ...) and so it will return List of Object[] containing the column values, one Object[] for each row, not Jointure1 instances.

Comment: @Chris Fixed it, thank you.